# ¿Cómo traducir la palabra "mirror" del inglés en el contexto de ser una URL donde se ha replicado cierto contenido?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario-técnico, informática

Es muy común tener, en diversos sitios web, una URL de descarga, acompañada de otras URL llamadas "mirror" donde se ha replicado el contenido haciéndolo disponible desde varias URL.

"Espejos" no me parece una traducción adecuada. ¿Cuál recomendarían ustedes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

De acuerdo a [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espejo_(Internet)), valdría "espejo"

> En Internet, un *espejo* (calco del inglés mirror) es un sitio web que contiene una réplica exacta de otro. Estas réplicas o **espejos** se suelen crear para facilitar descargas grandes y facilitar el acceso a la información aún cuando haya fallos en el servicio del servidor principal.

Otras referencias:

[Mirror (sitio espejo)](http://uft-digital.wikidot.com/mirror-sitio-espejo) en Glosario de términos para el periodismo en la era digital

> Un sitio espejo es un sitio web que es una réplica de un sitio ya existente, utilizado para reducir el tráfico de red

[Mirror site / Sitio espejo](https://glosarios.servidor-alicante.com/informatica-e-internet/mirror-site) en Glosario Informática e Internet

> Sitio web copiado a otro servidor con el propósito de facilitar el acceso a sus contenidos desde el lugar más cercano o más conveniente para el usuario.

[En México, abundan fraudes con páginas ‘espejo’ en Internet](https://laverdadnoticias.com/economia/En-Mexico-abundan-fraudes-con-paginas-espejo-en-Internet-20180507-0050.html) (periódico La verdad)

> A la fecha persisten y van en aumento los sitios de Internet que tratan de engañar a los cibernautas haciéndoles creer que harán negocios con empresas consolidadas, cuando en realidad se trata de páginas “espejo”

Comment: Podría ser "sitio espejo" (en mi opinión), pero "espejo" a secas suena desagradable para mí. Gracias por la respuesta!

Answer (score 2):

Creo que la mejor opción es "réplica", y como verbo, "replicar".

Comment: esta podría ser una buena respuesta para el verbo pero no para el sustantivo

Comment: ¿"Replicar un sitio" no te parece una frase adecuada? Creo que "espejear" es objetivamente horrible :D

Comment: @DanielGray *Replicar un sitio* no suena idiomático.

Comment: bueno, el realidad deberia ser "reflejar" por que un mirror y una replication son cosas diferentes

Comment: @Alejandro no veo por qué no pueda sonar idiomático. Replicar es crear una imitación de algo, ¿no? Lo mismo puede ocurrir con un objeto físico o una página web.